# Python doesn't work locally

Tags: python

I'm trying to get python to run programs locally. I got a program that runs fine online:

```
import random

def playgame():
    s = random.randint(15,99)
    POSS = range(1,7)
    if not s % 7:
        print("I only play when I'm certain of winning, try again!")
        return
    while s > 0:
        choice = 0
        while choice not in POSS:
            choice = int(input("Select a number between 1 and 6: "))
        s -= choice
        print("You subtracted {}, leaving {}".format(choice,s))
        if not s % 7:
            comp_choice = 1
        else:
            comp_choice = s % 7
        s -= comp_choice
        print("I subtracted {}, leaving {}".format(comp_choice,s))
    print("I win!")

playgame()
```

But this won't run on my machine. I installed python 3.3.3 and I am in the Python GUI and I just paste it in and I get Syntaxerror: Multiple statements found while compiling a statement...

Full error:

```
>>> import random

def playgame():
    s = random.randint(15,99)
    POSS = range(1,7)
    if not s % 7:
        print("I only play when I'm certain of winning, try again!")
        return
    while s > 0:
        choice = 0
        while choice not in POSS:
            choice = int(input("Select a number between 1 and 6: "))
        s -= choice
        print("You subtracted {}, leaving {}".format(choice,s))
        if not s % 7:
            comp_choice = 1
        else:
            comp_choice = s % 7
        s -= comp_choice
        print("I subtracted {}, leaving {}".format(comp_choice,s))
    print("I win!")

playgame()
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
>>>
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. (and what's "the Python GUI" here?)

Comment: what is the complete text of the error message? Did you try saving the file in a text editor and running it from the command line?

Comment: The pythin GUI is something that followed with the python I downloaded. I am totally new to python...

I downloaded it from here: http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.3/

I don't know how to run it from my CMD but it won't run from the python console.

Comment: if I type python into my CMD nothing happens. But I got a python terminal that I can open like any other program.

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine after just a copy/paste, both into the terminal and as a module. Are you sure the code you posted here is **exactly the same** as what you ran?

Comment: Now I'm trying to execute simple programs like:

def sieve1(n):
    loops = 0
    numbers = set(range(2, n))
    for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        for j in range(i * 2, n, i):
            numbers.discard(j)
            loops += 1
    return sorted(numbers), loops
print sieve1(100)


But it won't do the ''print'' part. Why not? Is anything wrong with it?

Comment: @user3200098 don't put code in comments. Python code without indents and newlines are worthless.

Comment: @user3200098 At the very least, `print(sieve1(100))` needs those parentheses I added... Anyway, that's a totally different question, and therefore it should not be a comment on this one.

Comment: This error is very likely from IDLE. In the console-mode interpreter, or the PythonWin IDE, it should either work, or raise an `IndentationError`. In IDLE, it tries to treat each block of input as a statement or expression and then compile and run it manually, and trying to compile this code (with three top-level statements) as a statement will fail with exactly that error.

Comment: "if I type python into my CMD nothing happens". That seems hard to believe. It should either start the Python interactive interpreter, or give you an error about not being able to find a program named `python`. If you want help with that, maybe copy and paste the `cmd` session so we can see exactly what happens.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot always paste a multi-line statement into the interactive interpreter—whether you're using the command-line interpreter, the IDLE GUI, or some third-party IDE.

Part of the reason for this is that the interactive interpreter attempts to help you out with indentation—which works great when you're typing, but when you're pasting code that's already indented, it just breaks the indentation. This doesn't *always* cause problems, but *sometimes* it does, and learning when it does and doesn't is really not worth the effort.

IDLE adds an additional problem: It first tries to figure out which things you've typed are separate statements, so it can pass them to the compiler, and if it guesses wrong… you get exactly the error message you saw.

Plus, it is very hard to notice (or debug) indentation problems in this mode. You may have accidentally selected an extra space before the first line and broken the whole thing, or… who knows?

[IPython](http://ipython.org) has a special `%cpaste` command that lets you paste a block of source code and let it figure out how to compile it, which almost always does what you want. [bpython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bpython) has a similar (but more graphically-oriented) feature. So, if you're willing to use an alternative shell, you can do this.

Alternatively, you can run Python in non-interactive mode. But at that point, you're better off just piping/redirecting input to it in the first place. And even better off just saving your source as a file and running the file as a script.

And really, that's the best answer here: save it as a file, run the file. If you want to run the file and then drop into the interactive prompt, just use the `-i` flag.

Or, if you're using IDLE, it's even easier: create a new window, paste the source, save, hit F5, and it automatically runs that file and then drops you into interactive mode.

Comment: I can paste multi-line code into the interpreter in the standard Windows console just fine.

Comment: @HenryKeiter because sometimes it works doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: Are you testing with code that has any dedents followed by indents? If not, any extra spacing it adds obviously won't have any effect.

Comment: @abarnert The only time I've seen it fail is when there are dedents all the way to the global level without a newline preceding them. The code in the asker's example, for instance, works without any trouble. Not that I'm saying it's a good place to do development, but it's usually an easy way to test one-off code snippets (such as those on this site) in my experience.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: Dedenting spaces and re-indenting with a tab (which is already a bad idea for other reasons, needless to say) can also cause a problem. But I don't think it's worth trying to teach the OP exactly what does and doesn't work with console-mode Python vs. alternative interactive interpreters vs. IDLE vs. other GUIs vs. … At least not when he hasn't even worked out how to run a single program yet.